# Podio : Troubles assigning reference for a Relationship app field

Tags: php, api, podio

I programmatically created an app with a relationship app field

```
$app = new PodioApp($attributes);
```

After it had been successfully created, I wanted to create a relationship app field

```
$field_id = PodioAppField::create( array (
                                        "type => "app",
                                        "external_id" => "test",
                                        "config" => array (
                                                        "label" => "Test field",
                                                        "settings" => array()
                                                    )
                                          ));
```

Indeed, the field is created in podio. Now, I want to assign the reference app for that relationship field and my code is as follow:

```
$settings = array( 
                "apps" => array (
                            array("app_id" => 10036463)
                          )
            );
PodioAppField::update($app->app_id, $field_id, array (
                                                        "label" => "Updated_test_field",
                                                        "settings" => $settings
                                                   ));
```

There is no error shown either on the screen or on log file. However when I check my app template on my workspace, the reference app to the relationship field is not set up.

So, if anybody could tell what's wrong with my settings, it would be nice :)

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config options are at: https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications

The settings name is not `apps` but `referenced_apps` and you can do this in one go. There's no reason to use 3 API calls when you can create your app with one:

```
$attributes = array(
  "fields" => array(
    array (
      "type => "app",
      "config" => array (
        "label" => "Test field",
        "settings" => array(
          "referenced_apps" => array("app_id" => 10036463)
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
$app = new PodioApp($attributes);
```

I've omitted all the other app attributes here. I've also removed `external_id` since one will be automatically generated for you.

Comment: Shouldn't settings be `"settings" => array((array("app_id"=> 10036463))` instead ? I tried both this one and yours but the 'referenced_apps' remain not attached in podio template. Could it be an API bug ?