# Podio - Relationship app field implementation

Tags: php, api, podio

A great thanks to @Andreas for answering my question at [Podio : Troubles assigning reference for a Relationship app field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756952/podio-troubles-assigning-reference-for-a-relationship-app-field), it helped me finding the special settings for all podio app fields.

Anyway, I still can't assign referenced apps to relationship app fields.

I've tried to create app with all the fields the following way :

```
$attributes = array(
            "space_id" => $ws->space_id,
            "config" => array(
                "icon" => DEFAULT_APP_ICON,
                "item_name" => "Test App",
                "name" => "TestApp"
            ),
            "fields" => array(
              array (
                "type" => "app",
                "external_id" => "test-reference-field",
                "config" => array (
                  "label" => "Test field",
                  "settings" => array(
                    "referenced_apps" => array(array("app_id" => 10048654))
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          );
          $app = new PodioApp($attributes);
```

But it does not create the app at all in the given workspace, so I created the app by calling static create() method instead:

```
$app = PodioApp::create($attributes);
```

Indeed, the app is created in the right workspace but the referenced app is not linked at all.
So, would it be an API bug or anything else I skipped in my code? Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is wrong and you should be using `referenceable_types` for your settings key and the value should just be an array of app_ids.

```
$attributes = array(
        "space_id" => $ws->space_id,
        "config" => array(
            "icon" => DEFAULT_APP_ICON,
            "item_name" => "Test App",
            "name" => "TestApp"
        ),
        "fields" => array(
          array (
            "type" => "app",
            "external_id" => "test-reference-field",
            "config" => array (
              "label" => "Test field",
              "settings" => array(
                "referenceable_types" => array(233461, 233464)
              )
            )
          )
        )
      );
$app = PodioApp::create($attributes);
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas! Could you please provide the link that has this documentation.